# 1:1 and onto proof of Z+ and Q+

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I'm looking for help finishing this proof
The details are laid out here:
http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=4733092#post4733092

if that doesn't work here is another format
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlbIl.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4DmC.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFL3A.png
it has to be proven in this way because that's what he asked for. i know there are other ways but thats not what we are doing

Comment: Please make the post self contained.

Comment: I'm unable to make sense of what you have at the link.  Crazy number of "[itex]" things...

Comment: Do you actually demand a bijective map or merely proof that one exists?  (A pair of injections, one in each direction is easy.)

Comment: ok i got new links up does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Presupposing that a pair of injections will suffice...

$\mathbb{Z}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$:  $n \rightarrow \frac{n}{1}$, the usual identification of the integers in the rationals.

$\mathbb{Q}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$: $\frac{p}{q} \rightarrow 2^{|p|} 3^{|q|}$.  Unique factorization implies injectivity:  $2^a 3^b = 2^c 3^d$ forces $a=c$ and $b=d$.  (The use of absolute values is unnecessary if you agree to not admit $-1/-2$ as a perfectly good member of $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$; they are if you don't.)